# Equivalent to ember engines in react

Tags: reactjs, ember.js

In ember.js [Ember Engines](https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines) let you compose multiple standalone applications into a single application. Is there an equivalent in react.js?

What I want to do is provide a generic login page and serve different applications depending on which customer signes in.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to handle including the appropriate bundle / script tag yourself. From what I've seen / heard, Engines are uniquely an Ember thing.